# How to replace special character?

Tags: javascript, html

Does any one know how to convert special characters to HTML in Javascript?
this is my code

```
rosHtml = rosHtml.replace(new RegExp("moreOptions("+previousIndex+")","gm"),"moreOptions("+currentIndex+")")
```

and i am using replace functionality code

```
return html.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
            .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
            .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
            .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
            .replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
            .replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
```

Comment: this is working moreOptions_1 to moreOptions_2 , but I want this moreOptions(1) to moreOptions(2)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think ampersand should be the last character to be replaced

Comment: `var p = document.createElement('p'); p.textContent = 'Ernie & Bert'; console.log(p.innerHTML);` – The browser can do escaping for you. What this really has to do with escaping for regexen I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

In the following link you can fork library for this problem.

Description: he (for “HTML entities”) is a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript. 
It supports all standardized named character references as per HTML, handles ambiguous ampersands and other edge cases just like a browser would, has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other JavaScript solutions — he handles astral Unicode symbols just fine

https://github.com/omidnasri/he